# Presence info of Skype for Business Online (Office 365) user

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business, ucwa, skypedeveloper

Sorry If I am giving too much details and if it is not in sync together.

my question is, **Is there any way by which I can show presence information of  Skype for Business Online (Office 365) user into our web application?**

In our web application we want to provide ability to our worker users, using which he can see the status or chat with shift super-wiser users. We don't want to do any configuration to on-premise Skype for business servers, we want to this through cloud. We are using HTML 5, JavaScript, C# for development purpose.

we have office 365 subscription where we have configured a azure active directory for few users. I think we'd need to perform authentication using Microsoft Graph API.

I searched on google and found that,

*

> Are applications created with Skype Web API able to communicate with
>   Skype for Business Online (O365) users?
>
> Ans: Currently Skype Web API apps
>   require a local on-premises Lync 2013 or Skype for Business server.
>   Online capability is in the roadmap but we do not currently have a
>   release date.

*

Documentation of Skype Developer Platform list various SDK's and API's to communicate with Skype. Only Lync 2013 SDK supports Skype for Business online but unfortunatly it doesn't have support for html & javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve a user's Skype for Business Online presence through the recently released and updated UCWA APIs.  After you register a custom app in Azure AD and do the UCWA Autodiscovery dance with the user's credentials:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/ucwa/AuthenticationUsingAzureAD

Retrieve the application resource, and parse it.   Make a POST to the makeMeAVailable resource to make the user available and set their presence:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/makemeavailable_ref

Or to retrieve it, call presence:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/presence_ref

I've created a [C#-based sample app](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console/) that you can use as a starter: it demonstrates how to sign in a user, perforom UCWA Autodiscovery for Skype for Business Online, and then set and access a user's presence.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response here.
I'm afraid (as you've probably figured out) that Skype for business user presence is not currently exposed through Microsoft Graph.  It is however something that we are looking at for the future, so thanks for feedback and your scenario.  You might want to log a feature request at UserVoice.

Comment: Is there any way of getting the online status into external SW? Maybe at least my own status, so that I can publish it anywhere?