# How can I get the phone number for a Skype For Business Online user?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to figure out how to fetch the phone number which is assigned to an Office365 user when they are [granted access to the skype calling feature in Office365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SkypeForBusiness/what-are-calling-plans-in-office-365/assign-change-or-remove-a-phone-number-for-a-user?toc=/MicrosoftTeams/toc.json&bc=/microsoftteams/breadcrumb/toc.json). I'd like to use a .Net SDK and perform this work from an Azure function app, granting access to the Skype APIs via an application registration in the Azure portal if possible.

I believe this information is available using PowerShell via the `Get-CSOnlineUser` commandlet which returns the `LineItem` property with the desired value, but I'd rather write this in .Net.

[It looks like this information isn't available in the MS Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333096/are-contacts-in-skype-for-business-accessible-via-graph-api). The [Skype for Dev Platform page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform) shows that the unified communication web API is probably the best fit, but the documentation seems to focus on meeting, presence, and contact management rather than user interrogation.

Comment: The Skype for business(online) user info is not currently exposed through Microsoft Graph. Please see, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061660/presence-info-of-skype-for-business-online-office-365-user

Comment: I see that answer discusses accessing and setting user presence. Does UCWA make the phone number available as well, or am I looking at the PS commandlets to get this done?